# Is it available?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US5771607](https://www.google.com/patents/US5771607)

Hello,

I would want to know the legal status of this patent?

Answer (score 2):

Using https://ramps.uspto.gov/eram/ one can find out that US 5771607 expired on 06/30/2002 for failure to pay maintenance fees.  The patent is no longer in force.